# C++ Input validation for strings with loop

Tags: c++, string, validation, if-statement

I'm trying to make a program in which the user enters in a number and a letter representing what unit of measurement their using (ex inches=i, feet=f, etc) then the letter inputted is used on a series of if statements to see which function to go to convert the number to how many meters it would be. I added an input validation for the units of measure(which are being used as a string variable).My problem is when I input the letter I want to use the program thinks what I entered is invalid even when the input is correct. I removed the input validation and also noticed that the string doesn't even go through any of the if statements. The code is something like this the #include  included:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
float inTOmeters(float);
float ftTOmeters(float);
float cmTOmeters(float);
float yTOmeters(float);
int main{
    float measurement, measurement;
    string unit;
    cout<<"Enter the number you want to be measured"<<endl;
    cin>>measure;
    cout<<"Now enter the unit of measurement you want to use"<<endl;
    cout<<"i=inches, f=feet, c=centimeters, y=yards, m=meters"<<endl;
    cin<<unit;
    while(unit !="i"||unit !="m"||unit !="c"||unit !="y"||unit !="f"){
        cout<<"Invalid input pick from I, m, c, y, or f"<<endl;
        cin>>unit;
    }
    if(unit=="i"){
        measurementm=inTOmeters(measurement);
    }
    if(unit=="c"){
        measurementm=cmTOmeters(measurement);
    }
    if(unit=="f"){
        measurementm=ftTOmeters(measurement);
    }
    if(unit=="y"){
        measurementm=yTOmeters(measurement);
    }
    else{
        measurementm=measurement;
    }

    cout<<"your measurement will be"<<measurementm<<"in meters."<<endl;
}
```

I didn't include the functions because I know they work. My question is how do I make it so my loop and if statements function when given the correct input? Also how do I make it so the code accepts capital letters of the correct input?

Comment: Your code contains a couple of errors... I would suggest to fix them first to be self-contained...

Comment: You can't have two variables with the same name. Possibly a typo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned, this code has numerous problems and could not possibly compile. Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;

float inTOmeters(float);
float ftTOmeters(float);
float cmTOmeters(float);
float yTOmeters(float);

int main()
{
    float input, measurement=0.0;
    char unit;

    cout<<"Enter the number you want to convert:"<<endl;
    cin>>input;

    cout<<"Now enter the unit of measurement you want to use:"<<endl;
    cout<<"i=inches, f=feet, c=centimeters, y=yards, m=meters"<<endl;

    while(true){

        cin >> unit;
        unit = std::toupper(unit);

        if(unit=='I'){
            measurement=inTOmeters(measurement);
        }
        else if(unit=='C'){
            measurement=cmTOmeters(measurement);
        }
        else if(unit=='F'){
            measurement=ftTOmeters(measurement);
        }
        else if(unit=='Y'){
            measurement=yTOmeters(measurement);
        }
        else if(unit=='M'){
            measurement = input;
        }
        else if(unit=='X'){
            break;
        }
        else{
            cout << "'" << unit << "'" << "is invalid. Choose i, m, c, y, or f." << endl;
            continue;
        }

        cout << input << " is " << measurement << " in meters." << endl;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems I see with your program right off the bat. From the code you've provided the variable `measure` has not been declared and you've declared two variables named `measurement`.

As for the input, have you thought about handling it with a switch statement? You can use characters for the different cases and write the default case to handle any invalid input.

Lastly, instead of a while loop you could just have your function `int main` with a return of `return main();` which would be a fine way to loop this simple program.

Answer (score 0):

A few errors

You never input unit, you need `cin >> unit;` somewhere.

Logic error, you used 'or' when you should of used 'and'.

```
 while(unit !="i" && unit !="m" && unit !="c" && unit !="y" && unit !="f"){
        cout<<"Invalid input pick from I, m, c, y, or f"<<endl;
        cin>>unit;
    }
```

I you think about it a minute you'll realise that unit does not equal "i" OR unit does not equal "m" is *always* true.